# html login form integrated with database through python

Tags: python, html, mysql, css

i have a login form of html

```html
<form action="some python file">
  username:<input type='text' name='u'>
  password:<input type='password' name='p'>
  <button type='submit' value='1' name='buttonvariable'>login</button>
 </form>
```

Now i wish to integrate my database (mysql) with this login form and
i have already created a sign up form which inputs the entry in the  table(named employee) inside database(named user).
How to write a python code such that when a user login this form then the input user and password are compared with the values present in the table(named employee) and if the values matched then the user is allowed in the portal otherwise an "error:invalid user" is displayed?

Comment: Hi, What have you tried?

Comment: i have created a sign up from that adds the entry in the database
example:(python code)
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> x=MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','pass')
>>> y=x.cursor()
>>> y.execute('use user;')
>>> y.execute('show databases;'')
>>> sql='''create table employee(
...    name char(20) NOT NULL,
...    pass char(30) NOT NULL,
...    contact INT(15) NOT NULL);'''

Comment: You could take a look at the Django lib. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/